# SQL Server Express backup and restore to other database batch

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, database-restore

I am trying to outsource some processes from my live database where a third party tool is importing data which first have to run through some scripts/changes because of quality before being implemented in live DB

So I thought I will create a second DB in the same server take my Backup batch and every time I make a backup I restore the Backup in the new db, where the third party tool is importing the data. Then I use this db to make some changes on another DB, which I then update into live DB.

Batch file:

```
osql.exe -S (local)\WAWI -U user -P password -Q "BACKUP DATABASE eazybusiness TO DISK = 'c:\WaWi-Backups\eazybusiness.bak'"
osql.exe -S (local)\WAWI -U user -P password -d master -Q "restore database Mandant_2 FROM DISK ='c:\WaWi-Backups\eazybusiness.bak' with replace"
```

But when running the script, the restore command is throwing the following error

> Msg '1834', '16', status '1', server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   The file ' C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11. WAWI\MSSQL\DATA\eazybusiness.mdf' can not be overwritten
>   be. It is used by the eazybusiness database.
>
> Msg '3156', '16', '4' status, server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   The file 'eazybusiness' can not in ' C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11. WAWI\MSSQL\DATA\eazybusiness.mdf' be restored.
>   Use WITH MOVE to a valid location for the file to identify.
>
> Msg '1834', '16', status '1', server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   The file ' C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11. WAWI\MSSQL\DATA\eazybusiness_log.ldf' cannot
>   be overridden. It is used by the eazybusiness database.
>
> Msg '3156', '16', '4' status, server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   The file 'eazybusiness_log' cannot be in ' C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11. WAWI\MSSQL\DATA\eazybusiness_log.ldf' restored
>   be. Use WITH MOVE to a valid location for the file to
>   identify.
>
> Msg '3119', '16', status '1', server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   Problems have been found in the planning of the restore statement. Preceding
>   Messages contain detailed information.
>
> Msg '3013', '16', status '1', server 'DBServer\WAWI', line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is stopped abnormally.
>   SpeakSelect voice optionsSearch this translation with BingThis is a good translationThis is a bad translation.

How can I restore the backup in another db through a batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are restoring the backup using a different name, but same file properties.  since the original database exists, you are trying to overwrite the same db, which is causing the failure.  You need to specify a different file name and/or location for each database data and log file, utilizing the WITH MOVE syntax.

See [RESTORE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation, specifically section "Copying a Database Using BACKUP and RESTORE".

Sample:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestDB 
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups 
   WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.mdf',
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.ldf';
GO
```

Comment: with the move command do I move the logs of my main database or the name of the logs saved in the restored file?